# Insertion of images into a SQL database

Tags: php

I am trying to input image into a localhost database, but my code refuses to cooperate. The "database[2].php" part is a PDO connection. The values of the database are id, image, and name and the database is called image.

```
<form action="image.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" class="inputBox">
    <input type="submit" class="inputBox"  value="go.">
</form>
<?php

include 'database[2].php';


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) === FALSE){
        echo "<div class='titleBox'>Please select an image.</div>";
    } else {
        $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $image = file_get_contents($image);
        $image = base64_encode($image);
        saveImage($name, $image);
    }
}

function saveImage($name, $image) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO image (name, image) VALUES (:name, :image)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':image', $_POST['image']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST['name']);

    if($stmt->execute()):
        echo "<div class='titleBox'>Image uploaded.</div>";
    else:
        echo "<div class='titleBox'>Image not uploaded.</div>";
    endif;

}
?>
```

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}` nothing in that statement will ever fire.

Comment: You also have a variable scope issue.

Comment: As @Fred-ii- stated you need to check for the value of the submit button, in your case: `if(isset($_POST['go.'])){...}`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Not really that, it's the name attribute PHP looks for (of which there is none for the submit-button) - not the value of it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos To check the value **FIRST** that input needs **a name attribute** `name="something"

Comment: @JorgeCampos you suggested `if(isset($_POST['go.']))` that should be more like `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['submit']== "go."))` ;-)

Comment: @Fred if only there was a `name="submit"` attribute too ;-)

Comment: @Qirel That's the underlying statement ;-)

Comment: Yes guys you are right... missed that, sorry

Comment: Yeah, you guy were right. Totally over looked that. Thanks.